# Is my disproof of showing $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $6n^2+27$ is prime correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Hi again this time I have a statement that I need to disprove. Again my answer differs quite much with the one from the solution book. Is my disproof correct? I appreciate your feedback.

**The statement to disprove:**

$\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $6n^2+27$ is prime

**My Attempt to disprove:**

Since to negate an existential statement is with a universal statement I figured to disprove the statement I will need to prove the following:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, 6n^2 +27$ is composite

**Here's the proof I have written :**

Suppose an integer $n$

It is given the number is $6n^2+27$

It can be written as $6n^2+27 = 3(2n^2+9)$

Let $k=2n^2+9$ note that $k$ is an integer and $1\lt k \lt 6n^2+27$

Hence, $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $6n^2+27=3k$

$\therefore 6n^2+27$ is composite

$\therefore 6n^2+27$ isn't prime

**This is the answer given in the solution book :**

Suppose $n$ is any integer

By factoring the expression,

$6n^2+27 = 3(2n^2+9)$

The definition of the prime number is as follows

An integer $n$ is prime iff $n \gt 1$, and for all positive integers $r$ and $s$ if $n=rs$ then either $r$ or $s$ equal to $n$

Because $(2n^2+9)$ are positive integers greater than $1$, and each is smaller than $6n^2+27$

So, $6n^2+27$ is a product of two smaller positive integers, each greater than $1$

Hence $6n^2+27$ is not prime

Comment: This seems too complicated.  $3$ divides any such value, so the only possible prime would be $3$, which is impossible because the minimal such value is $27$.  I would say both arguments are (slightly) incomplete since they don't explicitly rule out $3$ as a value.

Comment: That is a *very* tedious argument when the idea can be described briefly: a multiple of $3$ that's bigger than$3$ is not prime, and $6n^2 + 27 \geq 27 > 3$.

Comment: To me, your solution and the answer from the solution book are sementically the same. Can you please point out where you see the difference? Lulu's answer is different (the second half of it, that is), and slightly shorter, I'd say.

Comment: @Matija I find it hard to recognize it is the same, since the wording used is quite different. The biggest difference I would say is that they use the definition of prime to prove that $6n^2+27$ does not comply. 
Since I am new to proofs, in these situations I question myself if it was necessary to give this extra definition to make my prove work.

Comment: I think you used this definition from line 5 to 6 in your proof without spelling it out, together with $k>1$ (and $3>1$).

Comment: The book's argument is  incorrect or incomplete, since they quote one definition of "prime" $(n = rs\Rightarrow n=r\,$ or $\,n = s)\,$ but their proof doesn't *explicitly* use that. Instead they claim it is not prime because it "is a product of two smaller positive integers, each greater than $1$".  If the book didn't already show how that is related to the stated definition, then the proof is incorrect (being incomplete, or worse).

Comment: The same critique above applies to your argument. You seem to be going back and forth between two different defintions of prime, so we cannot judge the correctness of your argument until we know what definition you are using, and whether or not any relationship between these definitions has already been *proved*. Further, at this level, you should  *prove* any claimed inequalities.

Comment: "Once again I have a theorem, but this time I need to disprove this theorem." Any time that you need to disprove a theorem, you are in trouble. By definition, a theorem is a statement that has been proved. If you could disprove a statement that has been proved, then everything around you would collapse, and mathematicians everywhere would curse your name. It is far better, and much safer, to prove a theorem, than to disprove one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your feedback. by reading your feedback I think I have made a mistake by using the word theorem instead of statement. I'll edit my post to make it more clear. The assignment is to disprove a statement, not a theorem. Sorry for the confusion caused.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer and the model answer are essentially identical (as is gnasher729's). There is no meaningful difference between them; they are just both rather verbose in slightly different ways. It may be worth it to spend some time on trying to see for yourself that they are indeed almost identical, as this will sharpen your eye for what is important about them.

I'd phrase the very same argument as follows (assuming we have "a positive integer is prime iff it is not the product of two integers greater than $1$" readily available in our toolbox):

> We can factorize $6n^2 + 27 = 3(2n^2 + 9)$. We then observe that $3 > 1$
> and $2n^2 + 9 > 1$, thus $6n^2 + 27$ is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

$6n^2 + 27$ is divisible by $3$. It is therefore not a prime unless it equals $3$. But then $6n^2 = -24$ which is impossible.